# nginx unknown directive health_check

Tags: nginx

I am new to nginx. I am using -

```
health_check uri=/some/uri
```

but on running the test with this command -

```
 sudo /usr/sbin/nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

I get the following error -

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "health_check" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/abc.conf:121
```

Can someone tell what is wrong here..? I have used apache2 to do all jing-bang but I do not have much knowledge about nginx..

Comment: http://nginx.org/r/health_check "This directive is available as part of our commercial subscription."

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to Nginx [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#health_check) :

> This directive is available as part of nginx commercial subscription.

Comment: Is there any similar, free alternative? Maybe with less, but still helpful health information?

Comment: Never tried, but maybe this [upstream_check_module](https://github.com/yaoweibin/nginx_upstream_check_module) will work for you